# How do I find a function given vertical and oblique asymptope?

Tags: calculus, functions, asymptotics

Vertical asymptote: $x=2$
Oblique asymptote: $y=8x+5$

How do I find an example of a function given these asymptotes?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange. This is not a "solve this for me" site. Please provide some additional information on the context in which this problem appeared and/or on how you have attempted to solve it so far. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** One such function can be taken as: $f(x) = 8x+5+\dfrac{1}{x-2}$.Another one would be $g(x) = f(x) + \dfrac{1}{x}$.